# Javascript get Object property Name

Tags: javascript

I passed the following object:

```
var myVar = { typeA: { option1: "one", option2: "two" } }
```

I want to be able to pull out the key `typeA` from the above structure.

This value can change each time so next time it could be `typeB`.

So I would like to know if there is a way for me to do something like the following pseudo code:

```
var theTypeIs = myVar.key();
```

This way when I can pass this object and I can pull out the first value of the object, in this case it is `typeA` and then based on that I can do different things with `option1` and `option2`.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

If you know for sure that there's always going to be exactly one key in the object, then you can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
theTypeIs = Object.keys(myVar)[0];
```

Comment: Yes, it will always be one object, the object is a param to a function being called and I just needed to tell what the 'key' was so I can determine what action to take with the 'vaule' portion.

Answer (score 19):

Like the other answers you can do `theTypeIs = Object.keys(myVar)[0];` to get the first key. If you are expecting more keys, you can use

```
Object.keys(myVar).forEach(function(k) {
    if(k === "typeA") {
        // do stuff
    }
    else if (k === "typeB") {
        // do more stuff
    }
    else {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: second one should probably be `typeB`.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to get the key name of `myVar` object then you can use `Object.keys()` for this purpose.

```
var result = Object.keys(myVar); 

alert(result[0]) // result[0] alerts typeA
```

Comment: This returns ["typeA"] not "typeA"

Answer (score 0):

**I was searching to get a result for this either and I ended up with;**

```
const MyObject = {
    SubObject: {
        'eu': [0, "asd", true, undefined],
        'us': [0, "asd", false, null],
        'aus': [0, "asd", false, 0]
    }
};
```

**For those who wanted the result as a string:**

```
Object.keys(MyObject.SubObject).toString()
```

**output:** `"eu,us,aus"`

**For those who wanted the result as an array:**

```
Array.from(Object.keys(MyObject))
```

**output:** `Array ["eu", "us", "aus"]`

**For those who are looking for a "contains" type method:**
**as numeric result:**

```
console.log(Object.keys(MyObject.SubObject).indexOf("k"));
```

**output:** `-1`

```
console.log(Object.keys(MyObject.SubObject).indexOf("eu"));
```

**output:** `0`

```
console.log(Object.keys(MyObject.SubObject).indexOf("us"));
```

**output:** `3`

**as boolean result:**

```
console.log(Object.keys(MyObject.SubObject).includes("eu"));
```

**output:** `true`

---

**In your case;**

```js
var myVar = { typeA: { option1: "one", option2: "two" } }

    // Example 1
    console.log(Object.keys(myVar.typeA).toString()); // Result: "option1, option2"

    // Example 2
    console.log(Array.from(Object.keys(myVar.typeA))); // Result: Array ["option1", "option2" ]
    
    // Example 3 as numeric
    console.log((Object.keys(myVar.typeA).indexOf("option1")>=0)?'Exist!':'Does not exist!'); // Result: Exist!
    
    // Example 3 as boolean
    console.log(Object.keys(myVar.typeA).includes("option2")); // Result: True!
    
    // if you would like to know about SubObjects
    for(var key in myVar){
      // do smt with SubObject
      console.log(key); // Result: typeA
    }

    // if you already know your "SubObject"
    for(var key in myVar.typeA){
      // do smt with option1, option2
      console.log(key); // Result: option1 // Result: option2
    }
```