# What's in an unknown JSON object/Array?

Tags: android, json, facebook-graph-api

I want to get a list of friends' names from the Facebook API in Android. In that process, I want to learn how to read JSON objects/Arrays.

I have JSONObject and/or JSONArrays that have been passed to me. I don't know what's in them*. I know how to read the data once I know what fields exist, but I can't read anything as far as I can tell, without a key. Even with the key, How can I tell what's in it?

Basically, I'd like a piece of code that looks like:

```
JSONArray mArray = response.getJSONArray();
String theEntireDatabase = mArray.getStringOFEntireDatabase();
```

and have it respond with a String that looks like this:

```
{
   "phoneNumber": [
      {
         "type": "work",
         "num": "11111"
      },
      {
         "type": "home",
         "num": "2222"
      }
   ],
   "address": {
      "state": "World",
      "address": "infinite space, 000",
      "city": "Android city"
   },
   "surname": "Swa",
   "name": "Android"
}
```

Having known nothing of what is in the database beforehand?

*it could be "color:" it could be "nuclear threat level:" for all I know.

I tried this, but it only gives keys: [Javascript get JSON key Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565077/javascript-get-json-key-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONArray mArray = response.getJSONArray();
String theEntireDatabase = mArray.toString();
```

This should work well. 
If you want the JSONArray pretty printed you can add this after the code I've just provided you.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonElement je = jp.parse(theEntireDatabase);
String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`JSONObject#keys`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys()) will tell you what keys are defined for the object. [`JSONArray#length`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#length()) will tell you how many entries are in the array (and therefore the range of values you can use for `index` with the other methods: `0` through `length() - 1`). [`JSONObject#toString`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString(int))/[`JSONArray#toString`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#toString(int)) will give you the string you've asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Jacksons built-in tree model feature.
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel

And your code will be:

```
public void parse(String json)  {
       JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();

       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
       JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(json);  

       Iterator<Map.Entry<String,JsonNode>> fieldsIterator = rootNode.fields();
       while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {

           Map.Entry<String,JsonNode> field = fieldsIterator.next();
           System.out.println("Key: " + field.getKey() + "\tValue:" + field.getValue());
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

besides the technical answers (JSONObject#toString(n) seems the easiest - see http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html),

I would often use two more pragmatic solutions:

1. look for an API documentation... I know, it sounds crazy, but some companies do offer such a thing
2. hack together a short javascript script to try the API and inspect the result in the developer console/firebug/whatever is handy

Comment: The developer reference had been a bit frustrating, but finding the .toString() method was the "key".