# how to get the root of nodejs module xml2js

Tags: node.js

I am using nodejs's module "xml2js" but I need to find the root of the result.

```
    parseString(data, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

gives me

```
{ 'the-listener': { child1: [ 'test' ], child2: [ 'test' ] } }
```

And I want to just get 'the-listener'.

Instead of console.log(result) what do I need to change that to in order to get just 'the-listener'?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565077/javascript-get-json-key-name

Comment: @RayStantz Thanks, it was.