# JavaScript nested properties

Tags: javascript, object, nested-properties

If I have an object with nested properties. Is there a function that will search all properties, and the properties with values that are other objects (which also have their own properties) and so forth?

Example object:

```
const user = { 
    id: 101, 
    email: 'help@stack.com', 
    info: { 
        name: 'Please', 
        address: {
            state: 'WX' 
        }
    }
}
```

In the object above is there a way I could simply call something like

```
console.log(findProp(user, 'state'));
console.log(findProp(user, 'id'));
```

Comment: You might consider using something like what's describe in this question: [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6491463)

Comment: I think this one might answer your question though: [How to get the key value from nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38083288)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The problem with that article, is all the answers are providing the direct location. Rather than simply requesting it anywhere in the object regardless of how many levels deep.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The second article was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That post is even better, as I'm using it to find unique properties so there would be no need for it to be in an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a recursive function which looks up nested items (Object and Array as well) for the matching key (i also added an array for the lookup):

```js
var user = { id: 101, email: 'help@stack.com', info: {name: 'Please', address: {state: 'WX' }, contacts: [{'phone': '00000000'}, {'email': 'aaa@bbb.ccc'}]}}

function keyFinder(object, key) {
  if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)) return object[key];
  for(let subkey in object) {
    if(!object.hasOwnProperty(subkey) || typeof object[subkey] !== "object") continue;
    let match = keyFinder(object[subkey], key);
    if(match) return match;
  }
  return null;
}

console.log('id', keyFinder(user, 'id'));
console.log('state', keyFinder(user, 'state'));
console.log('phone', keyFinder(user, 'phone'));
console.log('notexisting', keyFinder(user, 'notexisting'));
```

`Object.hasOwnProperty` guards against iterating over or retrieving built-in properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function findProp(obj, search) {
   if(key in obj) return obj[key];
   for(const key in obj) {
     if(typeof obj[key] === "object" && obj[key] !== null) {
       const res = findProp(obj[key], search);
       if(res) return res;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: You may want to add a check to make sure `obj[key]` isn't `null`, or else an exception will be thrown when trying to check `key in obj` on the next recursion.

Comment: @CRice right, thanks.