# Find the matching object structure from a complex object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a sample object structure like below

Even though there are three types of addresses (`address, employeeAddress, shippingAddress`), they all represent the same data structure called address. From this object structure, I need to get all the addresses from the above structure.The object structure might be defined in using a JSON Schema format.
Also the addresses need not be always as part of the same hierarchy. For example in the above, `shippingAddress` and `employeeAddress` are at different hierarchy.
I tried with object's hasOwnProperty, but did not work the way as expected. Did not get much help from the `filter` method in `lodash` also. Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

```js
{
  "user": {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Steve",
    "address": {
      "houseNo": "24",
      "city": "CA",
      "country": {
        "code": "US",
        "name": "United States"
      }
    }
  },
  "employee": {
    "employeeID": "443434",
    "employeeName": "Steve",
    "employeeAddress": {
      "houseNo": "244",
      "city": "NJ",
      "country": {
        "code": "US",
        "name": "United States"
      }
    }
  },
  "assistant": {
    "assitantID": "443434",
    "employeeName": "Steve",
    "shippingDetails": {
      "shippingAddress": {
        "houseNo": "2444",
        "city": "LA",
        "country": {
          "code": "US",
          "name": "United States"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's right @NenadVracar. I wanted to get the matching structures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use recursion for this and create a function that takes input data and schema object. Then on each level another function checks if the current object matches schema structure.

```js
const data = {"user":{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Steve","address":{"houseNo":"24","city":"CA","country":{"code":"US","name":"United States"}}},"employee":{"employeeID":"443434","employeeName":"Steve","employeeAddress":{"houseNo":"244","city":"NJ","country":{"code":"US","name":"United States"}}},"assistant":{"assitantID":"443434","employeeName":"Steve","shippingDetails":{"shippingAddress":{"houseNo":"2444","city":"LA","country":{"code":"US","name":"United States"}}}}}

const schema = {
  houseNo: null,
  country: null,
  city: null
}

function match(o1, o2) {
  return Object.keys(o1).every(k => k in o2);
}

function get(data, schema) {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce((r, e) => {
    if (match(data[e], schema)) r.push(data[e]);
    else if (typeof data[e] == 'object') r.push(...get(data[e], schema));
    return r;
  }, [])
}

const result = get(data, schema);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: The const 'types' are not known actually. All I know is the structure of 'address'

Comment: @Apps How would you define the structure?

Comment: something like a JSON schema. Where we have the type and properties within that if it's object.

Comment: See update you can play with schema and matching function but the principle stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plain JS version of one [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43533282/295783)

```js
var user = { "user": { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Steve", "address": { "houseNo": "24", "city": "CA", "country": { "code": "US", "name": "United States" } } }, "employee": { "employeeID": "443434", "employeeName": "Steve", "employeeAddress": { "houseNo": "244", "city": "NJ", "country": { "code": "US", "name": "United States" } } }, "assistant": { "assitantID": "443434", "employeeName": "Steve", "shippingDetails": { "shippingAddress": { "houseNo": "2444", "city": "LA", "country": { "code": "US", "name": "United States" } } } } }

function findProp(obj, prop) {
  var result = {};
  function recursivelyFindProp(o, keyToBeFound) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (key) {
      if (typeof o[key] === 'object') {
        if (key.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyToBeFound) !==-1) result[key]=o[key];
        recursivelyFindProp(o[key], keyToBeFound);
      } else {
        if (key.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyToBeFound) !==-1) result[key]=o[key];
      }
    });
  }
  recursivelyFindProp(obj, prop);
  return result;
}
console.log(
  findProp(user, "address")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```