# How to map through a nested object in ReactJS and display all keys and values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-map

I am trying to display a list of fields that have been changed upon saving. To do this, I need to map through a very complex object consisting of both objects and arrays. The issue is in this part of the object right now:

```
suppressionRules: {
     additional_offer_ids: [2568]
     duration: {type: "days", amount: 7}
     suppression_type: "accepted"
  proto__: Object
}
```

For some reason, it's coming up as this when I display it:

```
suppressionRules: [object Object]
```

This is the function I'm using to display the changed fields in the object:

```
    function NumberList() {
      if (initialValues !== formValues) {
        const listItems = Object.keys(getChangedValues).map(item => {
          console.log(item + ' ' + getChangedValues[item]);
          return <li>{`${item}: ${getChangedValues[item]}`}</li>;
        });

        return <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
      }
      return null;
    }
```

I need help on how to make it so that the suppressionRules actually shows the fields inside of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the key value from nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083288/how-to-get-the-key-value-from-nested-object)

Comment: You are converting nested objects to string. One way is to do that conversion with `JSON.stringify`. `${JSON.stringify(getChangedValues[item])}`. That at least will avoid `[object Object]` in your output. Possibly you want a nested iteration though.

Comment: @trincot how would i go about a nested iteration?

Comment: Take the object and iterate it, just like you already iterate the outer object. If the nesting can be deeper still, then consider recursion. There are lots of Q&A on this site on how to iterate nested objects.