# Using JSON to Populate Properties of a DataGridView

Tags: c#, arrays, json, winforms, datagridview

Recently, I have been dabbling in reading json data into my C# code with the intent of storing property data in the json file to be loaded at run time. For example, I'd like to make a json file for each datagrid and have each column represented as a unique as a section in the json file; something like this:

```
[
    {
        "colWidth": 1,
        "rowHeight": 10,
        "moreStuff": 20
    },
    {
        "ColWidth": 2,
        "rowHeight": 100,
        "SecondBAID": 200
    },
    {
        "ColWidth": 3,
        "rowHeight": 1000,
        "moreStuff": 2000
    },
    {
        "ColWidth": 4,
        "rowHeight": 10000,
        "moreStuff": 20000,
        "someArray: [true, 5, "Column notes"]
    },
    {
        "ColWidth": 5,
        "rowHeight": 100000,
        "moreStuff": 200000,
        "evenMoreStuff":300000
    }
]
```

The code I am currently using to read this file and assign the data is as follows:

```
        public static void LoadJson()
    {
        string json;
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"test.json"))
        {
            json = r.ReadToEnd();
        }
        dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

        var list = new List<MyClass>();
        foreach (var section in array)
        {
            var si = new MyClass();
            if (section.Whatever!= null)
            {
                si.Test1 = section.Whatever;
            }
            if (section.Whatever2!= null)
            {
                si.Test2 = section.Whatever2;
            }
            if (section.Whatever3!= null)
            {
                si.Test3 = section.Whatever3;
            }
            if (section.Whatever4!= null)
            {
                si.Test4 = section.Whatever4;
            }

            list.Add(si);
        }
    }
```

I have a few questions regarding this though...

1) Is there an easier way to filter out null values? Sometimes I want the property of a column to be the default value, and I'd rather not nest dozens of if statements if possible. Is there a way to basically say "If this property doesn't exist in the json section, just ignore it"

Presently I am just iterating through all of the possible properties, doing a simple get/set in the MyClass, and storing the variables (For this example, I use "whatevers" so I don't post hundreds of lines of code; the whatevers represent legitimate fields in the json file.

2) I am currently adding each section of the json file to a dynamic array. How can I achieve this when I want to add an array of properties to the dynamic array? I'd like to change the C# code such that if I have a nested array, it will be added to some sort of multi level list. What is the best way to do this?

I'm using this ([Is it possible to have nested array json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45365601/is-it-possible-to-have-nested-array-json)) as a reference to nest arrays in the json.

Any advise would be awesome!

Comment: You should do some research on data binding.  In part it sounds like you are trying to get the grid settings *and* data from the file.

Comment: I had intended to store the data of the datagrid in a SQL database. As the users added / removed rows it would either add new rows to the SQL database, or delete them. Is there a better way to do this?