# Get field name of a javascript object with object's field as parameter

Tags: javascript

I have an object, like

```js
let foo = {
  firstName: 'David',
  lastName: 'Divad'
};
```

I want to get string 'firstName' of `foo.firstName`.
I found there is a way to get it but need to hard code the index:
[Javascript get Object property Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565077/javascript-get-object-property-name?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I can get 'firstName' by call Object.keys(foo)[0]
But I don't want to hard code the index because if the index was changed, I could not detect error in code at the compile, validation time. So I need to get string field name from field foo.firstName.

I wonder if there is a function such as getFieldName below do to that.
For example :

```
let foo = {
  firstName: 'David',
  lastName: 'Divad'
};

console.log(getFieldName(foo.firstName));  // expect print out 'firstName'
```

or

```
console.log(getFieldName(foo, foo.firstName));  // expect print out 'firstName'
```

**Is there any way to get field name of a javaScript object with object's field as parameter?**
Can anyone give me an idea?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565077/javascript-get-object-property-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565077/javascript-get-object-property-name)

Comment: you can get the list of them with Object.keys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript get Object property Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565077/javascript-get-object-property-name)

Comment: thank you all for answers, i mean i need to get string field name with object's  field as parameter without any index hard code. Just field as parameter. I have just update the question.

Comment: You mean `let key = foo["firstName"] ? "firstname" : "Not available"`

Comment: Or `let found = Object.keys(foo).includes("firstName")`

Comment: @mplungjan : no, i did not mean that. Could you please check my background note: I don't want to hard code 'firstName' or index because if the field name or It's index was changed, I could not detect error in code at the compile, validation time. So I need to get string field name from field foo.firstName.

Comment: Your comment or background makes no sense. Sorry

Comment: Please give more examples of input and expected output

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you very much for your support. My example of input is json object and its field : foo and foo.firstName.  And expected output is string 'firstName'.  Is It possible to do that?

Comment: You are asking to find .firstName without hardcoding firstName but using firstName as a parameter to find firstName - Please show the actual JSON and explain what you have available to find the key. It is not clear how to find an actual string without using some kind of comparison

Comment: @mplungjan I'm sorry for my confuse question. I mean i need to get string 'firstName' by foo.firstName, not the hard code index 0 from Object.keys(foo)[0] because if index was changed I could not detect the coding issue. 
Is It possible to do that?

Comment: If you have the word firstName, why do you need to get the string "firstName" from the object?

Comment: @mplungjan because string "firsName" will be changed dynamically when i changed the field name  foo.firstName.  For example I have a sort function which can sort by any fieldname as parameter, I can reuse code.

Comment: So you have an object and a function `let foo = {
  firstName: 'David',
  lastName: 'Divad'
};

console.log(getFieldName(foo.firstName));`
What could change here and how would you expect to find it?

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you for taking your time. I mean I expect a function such as getFieldName which can return string "firsName" from foo.firstName or string 'lastName' from  foo.lastName .

Comment: That still makes no sense at all. If you already in your hand have the word "firstName" to be able to construct "foo.firstName" then you seem to just want to know if the key exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `Object.keys()`

```js
let foo = {
  firstName: 'David',
  lastName: 'Divad'
};

console.log(Object.keys(foo)[0]);
```

Comment: Huge dupe......

Comment: thank you for the answer, i mean i need to get string field name with object's field as parameter without any index hard code. Just field as parameter. I have just update the question. Could you give me any idea?

Comment: @mplungjan that not dupe, please help me :( I have just update the question

Comment: @HieuTran Nothing in your update not making this a dupe. Unless you are not explaining what you actually need

Comment: @mplungjan I have update and explain what I need. Could you please help me?

Comment: @HieuTran I commented. Please answer my comments

Comment: @mplungjan: Ok, i have just answered your comment. Could you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get field name from this and iterate it

```
Object.keys(foo);
```